# How to delete an entity by two attributes in Hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc

i've come across a problem in these days, which would be simple for other languages, like php, but the project I'm doing is in Spring MVC.
The question is: In *Spring MVC*, how can i **delete an entity with two attributes ids coming from this entity**?

Example: "**Delete from Entity Where id1 =: id1 and id2 =: id2**" (This is the query that i want)

Thanks for the attention.

What i was trying ...

```
public boolean remover(int idUsuario, int idCategoria) {

    EntityManagerFactory factory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(PERSISTENCE_UNIT);
    EntityManager manager = factory.createEntityManager();


    String hqlStr = "delete from UsuarioEscolheCategoria where idUsuario = :idUsuario and idCategoria = :idCategoria";

    Query query = null; 


    try {

        query = manager.createQuery(hqlStr);

        query.setParameter("idUsuario", idUsuario);
        query.setParameter("idCategoria", idCategoria);

        query.executeUpdate();

        manager.close();
        factory.close();

        return true;

    }catch(Exception e) {
        return false;
    }

}
```

If i take the exception, it gives me:

[image: Exception error]

Comment: You can use criteria api, native query etc.. What have you tried so far?

Comment: I updated the question with what I tried

Comment: You should remove ":" in the setParameter method. Example :         query.setParameter("idUsuario", idUsuario);

Comment: You should use the necessary properties to see the executed sql-queries from hibernate. That should help you

Comment: It returns me javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: Executing an update/delete query. Is there any way to circumvent this exception?

Comment: Can you try to add @Transactional annotation to your method?

Comment: I tried, but the same mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
String hqlStr = "delete from UsuarioEscolheCategoria where usuario.idUsuario = :idUsuario and categoria.idCategoria = :idCategoria";
```

The important part is `usuario.idUsuario` and `categoria.idCategoria`. That way you're making a reference to the attribute type `Usuario`, which is on your model class.

Answer (score 0):

you prblem is the session factory, check how you  have created it, here a simple usefull example:

```
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;


    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    protected Session getSession() {
    return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    }

    public void deleteById(Integer id) {
        Query query = getSession().createSQLQuery("delete from TABLE where id = :t_id");
        query.setInteger("t_id", id);
        query.executeUpdate();
    }
```